# How to migrate in different databases?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this software and I need to create new institutions (like kindergardens). How to migrate into that new database?

```
if ($newDb) {
      Config::set('database.connections.th', [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'kindergarden'.$institutionId,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'timezone' => '+00:00',
        'strict' => false,
    ]);
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('migrate');
    }
```

And migrations are like

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name', 100);
        $table->string('last_name', 100);
        $table->tinyInteger('gender');
        $table->date('date_of_birth');
        $table->string('address', 150);
        $table->string('phone_number', 20);
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('status')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the non default database connection in your table migration

```php
Schema::connection('th')->create('students', function (Blueprint $table)
```

This will inform `artisan` to migrate this table to the specified database in your configuration

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-tables)

**Database Connection & Table Options**

If you want to perform a schema operation on a database connection that is not your default `connection`, use the connection method:

```php
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});
```